# SQL Server 2008 R2 database size

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How to find the default size of database in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I can try this

```
select * from sys.dm_db_file_space_usage
```

but it should not give the result.

Comment: The default for pretty much every new DB property is to make a copy of the *model* db into the new one. So, query the size of model.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID() 
GROUP BY database_id
```

Choose your database in query panel or you can use `USE DATABASE_NAME GO` at top of this code.

--EDIT--

I found built-in stored procedure for this :
`EXEC sp_helpdb @dbname= 'your_database_name'`